# Toshiba T2204A Air recirculation solenoid controller

Tags: digital-logic, relay, solenoid

please help me sorting out the pinout of the Toshiba T2204A. I spent more than a week of googling for datasheet, however the closest I could found is a similar package 2SK150A.  I'm unsure this could be used as a replacement, or at least I could put single TO packaged fet or transistors directly.

The circuit assembly controls a vacuum solenoid utilizing a Left-Middle-Right position switch by allowing to select open air or re-circulation for the Heat and Bi-Level modes only.
The relay stopped reacting on the rec/free switch, found the T2204A shorted.
I've disassembled the schematic of the circuit and made some measurements for the logic.
YG RL GY B are  the color codes of the wires coming from the mode selector switch of the heater controller - DEF(ogger), Heat, BI-L(evel), Vent and OFF modes.
1 means 12V on wire, 0 is no voltage.

The B wire receives +12V or GND from the Rec/Free switch.
GY wired to the indicator light for the re-circulation mode.
LB is the ground from the heater fan switch.
RL has 12V in case the Heat or Bi-level mode selected (these are the modes which can be controlled by the free/rec switch), otherwise 0V.
YG is the solenoid, which opens free air on 12V and closes on 0V, grounded to the chassis.

- I'm not sure the IC is a dual transistor or a mosfet and what could be the proper pin arrangement. Can you help me understanding the schematic?
- Also not sure the purpose of R1 & Vr, for first glance looks like a voltage divider, I assume it may function to slowly charge/discharge the C1 capacitor.

[image: Modified schematic with mosfets]
[image: Schematic and truth table]
[image: Wiring diagram of th]
[image: Heater controller]
[image: Relay circuit Top]
[image: Relay circuit Bottom]

Comment: Redraw and double check your schematic. Draw the mosfets as two separate mosfets. At the moment, your schematic makes no sense. Show a picture of the device so we can see all the markings.

Comment: Hi, I've checked the schematic a few times, I think that's how it is. Added some more images. The cap was removed to be able to lean the chip to the back.  Regarding the mosfet, I'm not 100% sure what it is, only assumption. The circuit has to toggle the relay, depending the Rec/Free switch gives a 12V or GND impulse, if voltage supplied through the RL wire.
In defogging mode the solenoid is "denied" (only external air can get in).
Heat and Bi-Level modes allowing the selection of re-circulation ow free air modes.
Vent mode has no re-circulation.
Off - the solenoid stays in re-circulation.

Comment: On the wiring diagram, this circuit is the Impulsgeber-Relais under the column of switches. The whole unit is powered from the two pin connector.marked with + and -.
Magnetschalter is the controlled vacuum solenoid.
The switches are actuated by the heat mode lever on the console.

Comment: Based on the age, I doubt there are mosfets involved.  I’d suggest the details of the T2204A are lost in the annals of time. The datasheet might not have made it out of Japan.

Comment: Possible, maybe the T marking is for transistor, it would make sense :)